# Javascript code returns Unhandled Promise Rejection: AbortError: The operation was aborted

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to run a simple contact form with html and javascript. I am trying to get filled out a contact form and  then post the data to api. Upon page load I immediately get an error for Unhandled promise rejection.

HTML is:

```
<form id="contact-form"method="post" class="form-horizontal contact-form" action="#">

                                    <!-- Honeypot SPAM Protection -->
                                    <input type="text" name="cf[honeypot]" style="display: none">
                                    <!-- END Honeypot SPAM Protection -->

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <input type="text" name="cf[name]" class="form-control required" placeholder="İsim">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <input type="email" name="cf[email]" class="form-control required email" placeholder="Email">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <input type="url" name="cf[url]" class="form-control url" placeholder="URL">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <input type="text" name="cf[subject]" class="form-control required" placeholder="Konu">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <textarea name="cf[message]" rows="6" class="form-control required" placeholder="Mesaj"></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <input type="submit" value="Gönder" class="btn btn-sm btn-block btn-primary">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/signup.js"></script>
```

And the javascript code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("contact-form").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var form=this;
        var URL = "https://v9jg33e7pa.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/beta/sendemail/";
        var data = {
         name: $(form).find("#cf[name]").val(),
         email: $(form).find("#cf[email]").val(),
         urlContact: $(form).find("#cf[url]").val(),
         subject: $(form).find("#cf[subject]").val(),
         message: $(form).find("#cf[message]").val()
       };



       console.log(data);

    if (""===$(form).find("#cf[honeypot]").val()){
       $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: URL,
         dataType: "json",
         contentType: "application/json",
         data: JSON.stringify(data),
         success: function () {
           // clear form and show a success message
           alert("yay");
         },
         error: function () {
           // show an error message
           alert("boo");
         },
       });
     }

    });
});
```

But when loading the page I get the following error: [image]

Could not figure out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the Amazon Cloud function is configured properly so that it can accept `POST`?

Comment: Yes I have tried from other sources it is working fine